# Depth first search Open and Closed list

Tags: list, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I am really stuck at the moment and I am going insane.

In the simplest of terms, when do you stop on Open and Closed lists with a depth first search?

Do you open and close every node until there are no nodes left?

Please help because I am going doolally here

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open list helps you in both depth first and breadth first searches to traverse your tree properly. Think about algorithms step by step. You are in a node with many children and your are going to expand one of them. After expansion there should be a mechanism to get back and continue your traversal. Open list performs that for you and tells you what is actually the next node to be expand. And the algorithm only clarify the order of child insertion into the list.

And Closed list generally improves the speed of algorithm. It prevents the algorithm from expanding pre-visited nodes. Maybe you reach node `A` that was expanded previously through another branch. This will let you cut this branch and try another path.

Heuristics are useful to get away from dead-end. In AI algorithms usually you are facing problems that they have many waste branches. By passing through each step you can add the path cost to a variable and when you want to add expanded nodes to your open list, considering it will help you never go through them. Otherwise, you will get into a trap and algorithm hangs.

Let me explain more with an example:
Consider the game [15-puzzles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle). You are going to solve it through an algorithm and you have to check all possible ways. (actually you are going to make a tree). When you move a tile in a direction that would be possible in your tree to move that in reverse direction in the next level, right? So you will never get out of such dead-ends and your algorithm hangs.

This was explanation of Open and Closed lists. You asked about when the algorithm finishes. Actually you will repeat the *expand and add to Open list* until you find your goal or Open list goes empty.