# depth first search graph open and close list

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ITEl.png

Hi, I am going over a question and there's not much on open and closed lists for examples anyone able to help?

Question - Use the depth-first search algorithm to traverse the following graph and record the details of “open” and “close” at each step.

```
what I have so far:
1) open =[A] close =[]
2) open=[F,G] close =[A]
3) open =[E,G] close =[F,A]
4) open =[C,D,G] close =[E,F,A]
5) open =[] close =[E,D,G,E,F,A]
```

I don't feel this answer is correct

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it isn't correct?

Comment: Because it is a 20 mark question in a past paper

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Depth first search Open and Closed list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063959/depth-first-search-open-and-closed-list)

Comment: no, it doesn't have figured out a bit more:
1) open =[A] close =[]
2) open=[F,G] close =[A]
3) open =[E,G] close =[F,A]
4) open =[C,D,G,G] close =[E,F,A]
5) open =[C,C,GG] close =[D,E,F,A]

what to do inorder to no create an infinite loop at c ?